# PERMANENTLY delete a firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I want to delete a project PERMANENTLY from my firebase, without it appearing on the pending deletion of the google devs site.
Its possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible on your own.  The pending deletion feature is intended to prevent people from making unrecoverable mistakes with their production projects.

You could try to [contact Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to see if they can do it manually.